# When do I need to create new Promises in javascript not fetch them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I have been diving into the world of async programming. I am building a ReactJS App and in it I am doing a bunch of async calls to the backend which talks to mongodb. I know that fetch calls return promises and need to be resolved but when exactly do you need to create your own promises and how do you know that something should be inside a promise or not? Please give a real example and a way I can mentally approach my code and say "Ok, this definitely needs to be wrapped in a new promise"

Answer (score 1):

Explicit promises are needed:

- When using an async JS API that depends on callbacks
- When managing async flow, such as with `Promise.all`, `Promise.race` etc
- When normalizing the return value of a function that only sometimes returns a promise

Example: Async functions that don't return promises

```js
setTimeout // Implemented before promises existed
setInterval
```

Example: (Good) setTimeout wrapped in promise

```js
await waitFor(5);

function waitFor(howManySeconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, howManySeconds * 1000);
  });
}
```

Explicit promises are often found in code as an anti-pattern, however.

Example: (Bad) Unnecessary promise wrapping

```js
async function getData() {
  // fetch already returns a promise, no need to create another one
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const data = await fetch('/some/data')
                       .then(response => response.json())

    resolve(data);
  });
}
```

Example: (Good) Implicit Promise

```js
async function getData() {
  return fetch('/some/data')
         .then(response => response.json());
}
```

Example: (Good) Using promise for control flow

```js
// Creates a promise that resolves only when all fruit types are fetched
function getAllFruits() {
  return Promise.all([
    fetch('/apples'),
    fetch('/oranges'),
    fetch('/pears'),
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are four general cases where it is useful to construct a Promise yourself:

- When you have an existing API that uses callbacks and want to use the standard interface provided by Promises (including when you want to wait for an event that is only going to fire once, at least only once that you care about).
- When you are mocking something that returns a promise
- Where you have a function which conditionally does something synchronously or asynchronously and want to provide a consistent return value.
- When you are writing something outside of JavaScript with a JS interface (e.g. a Node.js module in C++) that should act asynchronously